# What is the part called that holds the upper pulley on an extension spring garage door?

Tags: garage-door, brackets, pulleys

I have an extension spring garage door that doesn't open and close smoothly, and many times it doesn't complete a cycle before jamming up. I recently discovered why - the stationary pulley is quite literally eating the piece it's mounted to.

[image]

Full imgur album here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Veg.jpg (First two images are closeups of the pulley that's eating its mounting piece and second is a wider shot of the matching piece on the other side)

I can't figure out what the piece the pulley mounts to is called. It's not the flag bracket, that's the vertical piece bolted to the wall that supports the pulley piece and the vertical track, and it's not part of the horizontal track either.

As an alternative to this exact part, since it may not exist, could I replace it with a piece of C-channel, unistrut, or even that right-angle hole punched stuff that holds up the opener and track ends?

As for make and model, I know the door is an old Raynor model but I haven't been able to find any information on something that old, and Raynor is more interested in selling me a new door than providing support for their old stuff.

Comment: Bearing in the pulley probably shot.  Will need a new new pulley and bolt.  Bracket might be okay(does not look too bad) or can bolt a piece of steel to the inside to stiffen.  Decent hardware store should have a pulley that will work.

Comment: I'm replacing pretty much every moving part on this thing since it could be up to 30+ years old, and lead times for new garage doors are out to Februaryish in my area. I have a shopping cart lined up for purchase once I figure out how much the door weighs and what to replace the part in question with.

Comment: Looks like you only need a new bearing on that pully and replacement angle iron.  My two doors are 25+ years old ( also helped a couple neighbors) and never saw a failure like that.

Comment: I believe that's called a cable drum.

Comment: Yeah... you don't need a new door and so on. You need to replace the pulley and bolt. About $5 from Home Depot. You can also get a length of "punched" angle iron for less than $20.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that a decent piece of angle iron would be sufficient to mount a new pulley to. You could get either solid angle iron and drill the holes precisely where you need them, or get the perforated stuff and hope the holes line up.

Drilling holes in steel isn't all that hard. It just takes patience and some sort of lubricating fluid to keep the metal and the bit from overheating.